# Pycharm Django connect to MSSQL databse

Tags: python, sql-server, django, pycharm

I am a totally beginner in django. If the question is stupid, please let me know how I should do.

I already create the pycharm django project and want to connect to the MSSQL database. I see most of the solving ways is using `django-mssql-backend`

but I am in company computer and our system does not has this package. And I used to use jupyter notebook to connect the databse successfully, here is the code I used in the jupyternotebook

```
database = pyodbc.connect("Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};"
                        "Server= DBName;"
                        "Database=Staging;"
                        "Trusted_Connection=yes;")
query1 = """
select *
FROM [Staging].[dbo].[viewname]

df1=pd.read_sql_query(query1,database)
df1
```

I am wondering can I do the same way in django project to connect to database?

[django project folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nCPK.png) Here is the django project folder. If I can do what I do in jupyternotebook, which .py should I add the code in?

Sorry for the stupid question and any help is really apprecaited!

Comment: Is there a reason you're using the native client? It was deprecated in 2012 (iirc) and doesn't support anything after SQL Server 2014.

Comment: @ThomA I just change it to ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server, sorry I acutally don't know the native client does not support anymore, and I tried ODBC Driver and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

In your jupyter notebook, you are connecting directly to the database and run bare SQL queries on it. But Django has a built in ORM (Object Relational Mapping), which can connect to MSSQL and you can run your queries in Django query form.

This link shows you how to connect your Django ORM to MSSQL:
https://igeorgiev.eu/python/django/python-django-connect-sql-server-mssql-database/

And this link shows you how to run Django queries:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/queries/

Comment: Hi Khanzadeh, thank you for the info! I am wondering when I set the settings.py file, where should I enter the "staging". This is the setting I currently have
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'Iamdatabase', # I create the name
        'ENGINE': 'mssql',
        'HOST': 'DB\MAIN2_LIVE',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'Trusted_Connection': 'yes',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
        }

Comment: There are different ways for managing environment variables for different stages of development and production. I believe you can look up the best practices and use them (It would be too long to describe here).